# Yahoo Messanger in linux

Tags: linux

I want to install YahooMessanger in my LINUX/Debian Machine.
I used ymessenger_1.0.4_1_i386.deb package but It's not installed showing dependency problems.

I used pidgin but It's not working for yahoo while gmail is working properly.

Any solution for yahoo messanger in Debian machine.

Thanks

Comment: What are the dependency problems? I notice from an old post on Ubuntu's forum (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=81895) that you need libssl0.9.6. Please provide us with more information.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Pidgin or Empathy?  Is there some feature of the Yahoo! Messenger program that these programs don't have?

Answer (score 0):

I use Pidgin regularly in Fedora. I have used it successfully in many other distros. What errors are you receiving? Perhaps you need to sign into your Yahoo account via the web first as sometimes, Yahoo gets funny about accounts that haven't logged in for a while.